# AngularJS: How to toggle element from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I use the following controller to toggle the content inside `li` tag?
Right now the content is rendered only after that span is clicked, but it won't hide if I click again the span.

Here's my code:

```
<span ng-click="get_menu_items(folder)>
  <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
  {{ folder.name }}
</span>
<ul>
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="file in folder.files">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="file_map[]" value="{{ file.id }}"  ng-model="file_map[file.id]" ng-click="update_selection(file.id)"/>
        <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
        <span>{{ file.name }}</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li menuitem ng-repeat="folder in folder.folders" ng-model="folder"></li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
scope.get_menu_items = function(folder){
    http.get("/api/folders/" + folder.id).success(function(data){
        folder.folders = data.data.folders;
        folder.files= data.data.files;
    })
}
```

Comment: It won't be hide at the moment

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create a boolean for show/hide and toggle it on your click method like.

```
scope.get_menu_items = function(folder){
   //if folder.folder exist means we don't need to make $http req again
   if(folder.folders){
      $scope.showFolder = !$scope.showFolder
   }
   else{
      http.get("/api/folders/" + folder.id).success(function(data){
       folder.folders = data.data.folders;
       folder.files= data.data.files;
       $scope.showFolder = true;
      })
   }
}
```

and add `ng-if` on your view like.

```
<span ng-click="get_menu_items(folder)>
  <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
  {{ folder.name }}
</span>
<ul ng-if="showFolder">
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="file in folder.files">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="file_map[]" value="{{ file.id }}"  ng-model="file_map[file.id]" ng-click="update_selection(file.id)"/>
        <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
        <span>{{ file.name }}</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li menuitem ng-repeat="folder in folder.folders" ng-model="folder"></li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add a global variable in controller as scope.
Outside controller, add a variable (for example called: `toggleVariable`) and assign it to false.
Inside controller put this:
`scope.toggleVariable = !scope.toggleVariable;`

In HTML, add to `ul` tag: `ng-show="toggleVariable"`.

Give it a try

Comment: I have a problem with this...if I have two `li` inside that `ul` element then the second `li` toggles content of first `li` item

Comment: Well you said that you want to expand and collapse the content of `ul` when you click on span, right?

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I want to expand the content inside of `li` when I click on span.

Comment: Ok, but which li? Both in the same time?

Comment: Yes, but only if I click on the second `li`. The first `li` works fine.

Comment: Are you sure that the content of `folder.files` and `folder.fonders` is not the same?

Comment: Yes, my second `li` has no content

Comment: Maybe the model can be wrong? What about: `model="folder.id"`

Comment: Or remove that model and check menuitem directive

Comment: The second `li` does not have any content when I click on it, but it also toggles the first `li`, that's the problem

Comment: `ng-show="toggleVariable"` is set in `ul` tag right?

Comment: No, it must be set on `li` tag

Comment: Well actually no, if you want to show the entire content of ul, you have to put it on `ul` as I told you. You put it on `li` only if you show or hide specific `li`